# PerformancePoint services 2013 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, performancepoint

I am trying to use performancepoint 2013 services to create a report that simple displays a set of columns from SQL Server Table.

Apparently, PerformancePoint services can only display data from tables when used with analysis services (which i do not have on my SQL Server 2008).

I am looking for a way to make this work:
- Being able to display few columns from a SQL Server table as a report on Sharepoint 2013 using performancepoint services. Is it even possible?

If not, then what are my alternatives?

Please help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The analytical reports in PPS only support Analysis Services as you mentioned. However what you can try is to connect to your data source using Excel and then build a PowerPivot model using that data. Upload the Excel spreadsheet containing the PowerPivot model to SharePoint and create a new Multidimensional data source that points to your spreadsheet, [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191197(v=office.15).aspx.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191197%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Another option would be to use Reporting Services or just simply Excel Services without PowePivot.